# S3 cp AccessDenied from AWS cli with root keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have the AWS cli installed on an EC2 instance, and I configured it by running `aws configure` and giving it my AWSAccessKeyId and AWSSecretKey keys so if I run the command `aws s3 ls` it returns the name of my S3 bucket (call it "mybucket").

But, if I then try `aws s3 cp localfolder/ s3://mybucket/ --recursive` I get an error that looks like

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Anonymous users cannot initiate multipart uploads.  Please authenticate.
```

I thought that by running aws configure and giving it my root key that I was effectively giving the aws cli everything it needs to authenticate? Is there something I am missing regarding copying to an S3 bucket as opposed to listing them?

Comment: Your IAM user/role will need to be assigned a Policy that allows it to perform the `CreateMultipartUpload` action - you can simulate policies through IAM to check whether it will work.

Comment: root access key and secret keys should have all the privileges. Try running the aws configure again -

Comment: Thanks @Naveen Based on your comment I tried using a different set of root keys I had on a different computer and it did work. I'm now puzzled as to why one set of root keys worked but the other did not. But at least your suggestion solved my problem.

Comment: I have added the same as answer for benefit for the community

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198981/1736679

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Root Access keys and Secret key have full control and full privileges to interact with the AWS. Please try running the `aws configure` again to recheck the setting and try again.

PS: it is highly not recommended to use root access keys - please give a thought is creating an IAM ( which take admin privileges- like root ) and use those.

Comment: Even if I do `aws configure` again, it still doesn't work.

Comment: **Update**: I was using non-root credentials, double check that. @Naveen Vijay is correct, you should be able to do anything with a root user, but be careful, for sensitive apps you should use IAM.

Answer (score 27):

Thought I would add in a very similar issue that I had where I could list buckets but could not write to a given bucket returning the error

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
>   CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied

If the bucket uses **server-side encryption** you'll need to add the `--sse` flag to be able to write to this bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be my issue.

Comment: do you mean `aws s3 cp --sse localfolder s3:///bucketname/`? that returns `error: argument --sse: Invalid choice` in my case

Comment: `--sse` should be specified after (`aws s3 cp localfolder s3:///bucketname/ --sse`)

Answer (score 8):

If you have environment variables `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_REGION` set, AWS CLI gives higher precedence to them, and not to credentials you specify with `aws configure`.

So, in my case, bash command `unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up commenting it out of my .zshrc. Don't forget that once you change your .bashrc or .zshrc, you need to restart your shell, or `source ~/.zshrc` for the changes to apply to your session.

Comment: this can be especially a case for ENVs in CI/CD tools